# DynamoDB Webflux Pagination

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, rx-java, spring-webflux

How to get all the results in DynamodB on a global secondary index using Webflux? The Below code only gives me 1700 results, my table has 20k results?

var queryConditional =
QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(Key.builder().partitionValue(status).build());
var index = dynamoDbAsyncTable.index(Attributes.STATUS);

```
Mono<Page<Table>> results =
        Mono.from(
                index.query(QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
                                .queryConditional(queryConditional).build()));


return results.map(
        page -> page.items().stream().map(Table::toCourier).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: Query results are paged. Probably you need to do something to fetch the next page. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/pagination.html

I was referring to "Using Third Party" section, and I'm using RX, it doesn't do auto pagination for me. Any idea about it?